# how to enable sharding in test environment

Tags: mongodb, sharding

How do I enable sharding in test environment? Here I am sharing what i have done till now, I have one config server:

Config server1: Host-a:27019

One mongos instance on same machine on `port 27017`
and two mongod instance shard:

- Host-a:27020
- host-b:27021

When I am enabling sharding on collection it gives me this error:

```
2016-01-12T10:31:07.522Z I SHARDING [Balancer]  ns: feedproductsdata.merchantproducts going to move { _id: "feedproductsdata.merchantproducts-product_id_MinKey", ns: "feedproductsdata.merchantproducts", min: { product_id: MinKey }, max: { product_id: 0 }, version: Timestamp 1000|0, versionEpoch: ObjectId('5694d57ebe78315b68519c38'), lastmod: Timestamp 1000|0, lastmodEpoch: ObjectId('5694d57ebe78315b68519c38'), shard: "shard0001" } from: shard0001 to: shard0000 tag []
2016-01-12T10:31:07.523Z I SHARDING [Balancer] moving chunk ns: feedproductsdata.merchantproducts moving ( ns: feedproductsdata.merchantproducts, shard: shard0001:192.168.1.12:27021, lastmod: 1|0||000000000000000000000000, min: { product_id: MinKey }, max: { product_id: 0 }) shard0001:192.168.1.12:27021 -> shard0000:192.168.1.8:27020
2016-01-12T10:31:08.530Z I SHARDING [Balancer] moveChunk result: { errmsg: "exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for cfg1.server.com:27019", code: 11002, ok: 0.0 }
2016-01-12T10:31:08.531Z I SHARDING [Balancer] balancer move failed: { errmsg: "exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for cfg1.server.com:27019", code: 11002, ok: 0.0 } from: shard0001 to: shard0000 chunk:  min: { product_id: MinKey } max: { product_id: 0 }
2016-01-12T10:31:08.604Z I SHARDING [Balancer] distributed lock 'balancer/Knowledgeops-PC:27017:1452594322:41' unlocked.
```

Comment: log file shows it fails to move chunks from one shard to another shard and also displays socket connection from host b side to connect with config server

Comment: The error is here: *exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for cfg1.server.com:27019", code: 11002*  It can't connect to that TCP port. Check your settings and firewall.

Comment: firewall is OFF ..and this socket connection error  raised by shard that is on another machine error raised as balancer move failed

Comment: Are you able to ping cfg1.server.com or telnet cfg1.server.com:27019 from the shard ? Also it would be great if you can post the results of rs.conf() on the primary of the shards and sh.status() on Mongo router as well as output of use admin; db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts") on router

Comment: How you have started mongod serers? And how you have added shards?

Comment: That is a connection error, and I don't think it has anything to do with MongoDB at this stage of your question. Check your network, hostname, DNS, firewall, etc.

Comment: Setting up and administrating sharded cluster is more of an administrative problem than a development problem. That means it is more of a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com